# Outlier detection using clustering and dissimilarity matrix in R

Tags: r, clustering, outliers

I have some problems in finding the outliers using clustering.

The data.frame is ~20000 observations and each row has mixed types of variables(numeric, nominal and binary). What I want to do is to detect the outliers by clustering.

I have calculated the dissimilarity matrix using daisy() function in R:

```
diss = daisy(data,metric="gower")
```

And I know I can use pam() and hclust() functions to do the clustering. But how do I find the outliers after that?

Here is my R code to find the outliers from pam():

```
kmedoid = pam(diss,k=10,diss=T)
centers = kmedoid$id.med
distMat = as.matrix(diss)   
distances = rep(-99,20000)   
for (k in 1:20000) {   
  distances[k] = min(distMat[centers,k])   
}   
outliers = order(distances, decreasing=T)[1:5]   
outliers = data[outliers]   
outliers
```

I don't know whether it is correct, because the result seems to be pretty different each time when I tried different value of k in pam().

So the main question is: **Once I have the "kmedoid" and "hc" calculated below, how do I find the outliers?**

```
kmedoid = pam(data,k=10,diss=T)
hc = hclust(data)
```

I did search Google, but there wasn't much info about this. I am not fluent in programming, so just using existing package and function in R would help me a lot:)

And **is there any better method to find the outliers?**

Thanks!

Comment: By definition of hclust algorithm, the nodes joined in at nearest the root/top of the tree have the largest distance from the others. Since distance is dissimilarity here, that means they're the most dissimilar to the others. That means they're more likely to be outliers (though that is not certain). Also, the choice of the linkage method in hclust will influence the shape of the tree and so the points that might look like outliers.

Comment: So, do I just check hc$height and choose the largest values to be outliers?

Comment: I used python for hclust, so not sure. But that's the gist of it. Large height does not imply outlier as some node will always be last to be added even if they really are all drawn from the same process. However, if a node really was an outlier you could reasonably expect it to get merged in at large height as it would not be similar to the other points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see. My problem now is that how I can do this in R? I don't know how to interpret the output of the hclust() function..

Comment: You may want to look at outlier detection algorithms such as LOF and LoOP. Using *randomized* clustering methods such as k-means and PAM will yield different results every time, because the clusterings are different.

Comment: I used lofactor() function in the DWwR package, but I had some problems. Do I put the data.frame "data" or dissimilarity matrix "diss" as the input of the function. I tried both. For "data", there is an error that "Error in scale.default(temp, x, FALSE) : 
  length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'." For "diss", the result has some Inf and NaN and I dont know why....

Answer (score 2):

To fill out my comments above with an example, in case it helps get a feel. Here are two clusterings of overlapping data from the iris dataset. The first has 50 nodes from one species and 2 from another - 'outliers' with respect to the main group. The second has all 50 from the same species.

[image]

[image]

There'll always be some nodes merged in relatively high and unless you know the true labelling it's not going to be clear whether relatively high = absolutely high. I think the asymmetry in the first graph compared to the second is interesting though.

Comment: Is there any method to rank the outlyingness from result of hclust? Since the dataset is large, it is hard to see outliers from just looking at the Dendrogram.